# collect 2 arrays CLLocationDegree in one array of CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, ios5, ios5.1

I need to draw a polyline on google maps on ios , I have  latitudes and longitudes in seperated arrays and I want to collect them in one array of CLLocationCoordinate2D, so plz help me to write the code that make this collection

Comment: You have C arrays or `NSArray`s? And what type you expect at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = malloc(coordinateCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
for(size_t i = 0; i < coordinateCount; ++i)  
{
    coords[i].latitude = latitudes[i];
    coords[i].longitude = longitudes[i];
}

// ... Use the array ...

free(coords);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your implementation or at least provide the exception message, because I just ran this code and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe he would prefer object approach using `NSArray`.

Comment: If the intent is to draw a polyline with MapKit, the end result should be a C array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, as that's what the API calls for. Hopefully we'll get clarification from the asker on the type of the original arrays.